# One project with multiple apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

Is it possible to run multiple rails apps from inside one **Cloud9 IDE** project? For example, I have the following structure...

MyApp (C9 Project)

- MyApp-API (Rails/Grape)
- MyApp-Web (Rails)

When I run `rails server -p $PORT -b $IP` via terminal in **C9** in the respective app directories (i.e., MyApp-API, MyApp-Web) they both appear to be running. However, when I do cURL requests or try browsing directly I am not able to reach routes as expected.

I assume it's because I'm running the rails servers with the same port/ip configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud9 does not (yet) expose multiple ports to the outside. One approach that could work is to put a small reverse proxy like [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) in front of you apps. You can run your different apps on arbitrary ports and let the proxy listen on `$PORT`. Then configure the proxy to forward to yours apps e.g. based on the path.

Comment: Thanks, I ultimately decided just ended up splitting the apps out into two separate projects.

Comment: Could you please explain more in detail? I am facing the same issue than Jason and i am not sure on how to install/configure ngix to proxy the request for the api on a different port (ex 15001) ?

Answer (score 0):

only if you place `API part` in `app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb` for example.
And set `route` for it, for example as domain `myapp.com/api/posts.json` or subdomain (api.myapp.com/posts.json)

Comment: That would make the two apps one app. I want to keep them separate.

Comment: then you shoud run 2 separate process of web server(unicorn, puma and etc.) for each app, and configure nginx(apache) to handle url request to the app streams.

Comment: My question more relates to how to achieve this using the Cloud9 IDE. I believe my configuration could be achieved without the need for another layer (i.e., unicorn, puma, etc) if C9 provides alternate debugging ports.

Comment: Hi, we do not provide multiple exposed ports yet. My advice is to use a ssh server. Please keep in mind that the proposed solution with a subdomain will not work in C9. we only have 1 subdomain available for every workspace. The routing is still a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can't be done. C9 apparently only exposes one port. I will most likely need to break the apps out into separate projects...

[How to use grunt serve in Cloud9 IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682120/how-to-use-grunt-serve-in-cloud9-ide)

Technically, I can run the API app on a different local port such as:

```
rails server -p 15001 -b $IP
```

Then I can connect to it with cURL requests or have the web app connect to it with that end point.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:15001
```

It's a bit of a pain but, at least there is a workaround.