# Grunt serve stopped working on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: gruntjs, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I have a workspace that used to work (yestarday). I configured it according [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682120/how-to-use-grunt-serve-in-cloud9-ide), + changed hostname to be 0.0.0.0:

```
  connect: {
      options: {
        port: 8080,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        livereload: 8081
      },
      ...
```

Those exact configurations used to work for me yestarday, and now I cannot get anything when running on browser:

```
http://project-user.c9users.io:8080/
```

BTW - this did not for me, as well:

```
`kill -9 $(lsof -i:8080 -t)`
```

Comment: Did you try with just http://project-user.c9users.io? You shouldn't need to append the port to the end of the URL unless you're trying to access something on port 8081 or 8082. Also, try [restarting your workspace](https://docs.c9.io/docs/restarting-your-workspace) and see if that works any magic.

Comment: Yes, no luck... Tried all ports. It used to work yesterday

Comment: Can you paste in images or text of the errors you're getting?

Comment: There is no error.. The page doesn't load..

Comment: Can you check out this [github project](https://github.com/cloud9ide/livereload-example) and see if you can find any differences with your implementation?

Comment: My configurations are pretty much the same: https://github.com/yanivefraim/todo-list-upgrade/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L69

Comment: @Mutahhir - the example you supplied is not working for me. I might be doing something wrong? I do: 1. npm install + 2. install grunt locally + 3. grunt